# C++ smart pointer needed for string object on heap?

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, heap-memory, shared-ptr

I triy to demonstrate my problem. I can not provide a full example, but I think my question will be clear.

I have this constructor:

```
mlt::Client::Client(const string& hostname, struct sockaddr *hostaddr)
        : content(nullptr),
          hostname(hostname),
          ip_and_port(mlt::Client::prepareIPandPort(hostaddr))
{ /* ... */ }
```

As you can see, I use a static function that converts hostaddr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libnet.h>

const string& mlt::Client::prepareIPandPort(struct sockaddr *hostaddr) {
    assert(hostaddr != nullptr);

    string *ipport;
    char clienthost[NI_MAXHOST];
    char clientport[NI_MAXSERV];
    int result = getnameinfo(hostaddr, sizeof(*hostaddr),
                             clienthost, sizeof(clienthost),
                             clientport, sizeof(clientport),
                             NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);

    if (result != 0) {
        cerr << "Error: " << gai_strerror(result) << endl;
        ipport = new string {"unknown"};
    }
    else {
        switch (hostaddr->sa_family) {
            case AF_INET:
                ipport = new string {string(clienthost) + ":"
                                     + string(clientport)};
                break;
            case AF_INET6:
                ipport = new string {"[" + string(clienthost) + "]:"
                                     + string(clientport)};
                break;
            default:
                ipport = new string {"unknown"};
        }
    }

    return *ipport;
}
```

The mlt::Client::ip_and_port is declared as:

```
const string ip_and_port;
```

In my understanding, I create a string on the heap and return the dereferenced content as a reference to a const string. This result is used in the initializer to initialize the const string member ip_and_port.

Does this produce a memory leak? What happens, if I call "delete some_client_instance" and the destructor mlt::Client::~Client() is called?

Would I have to use a smart pointer (std::shared_ptr) in mlt::Client::prepareIPandPort? And if so, how would this piece of code look like?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: How did you declare ip_and_port? This is important to answer.

Comment: I'm confused. How can `ip_and_port` be declared with identifier `hostname` ?

Comment: Why a pointer? you could have return string, it would have done the job.
Something more like :
string  mlt::Client::prepareIPandPort(struct sockaddr *hostaddr) {
....

Comment: I thought that the string would only exist locally and after the stack is left, the variable would be killed (removed stack)

Comment: ok, so remove the pointer, and use std::string directly instead. It will be better.

Comment: @Greg thank you. This works. I think I still have to learn when to return a reference and when to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this causes a memory leak. You need to call `delete some_client_instance` at the end of your function.

Ideally, you should:

- Return a plain string (not a reference) in `mlt::Client::prepareIPandPort`
- Use a plain string for `ip_and_port`
- Initialize `ip_and_port` like below

This way, the string will be created only once, and never copied.

```
mlt::Client::Client(const string & hostname, struct sockaddr *hostaddr)
        : content(nullptr),
          hostname(hostname),
          ip_and_port(std::move(mlt::Client::prepareIPandPort(hostaddr)))
{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I get compiler warnings now:
-----------------
moving a temporary object prevents copy elision [-Wpessimizing-move]
          ip_and_port(move(mlt::Client::prepareIPandPort(hostaddr)))